# Setting up a text page using a php string of code

Tags: php

It will be placed within a template that returns dynamic channels

```
Php linking thats dynamic > http://domain.com/text.php?content=yourtext

doing so returns the text. "yourtext"
```

what i mean by this is "yourtext" will be added into embed codes thus being dynamic.

i am basically reconstructing a streaming sites layout.

EXAMPLE:

```
<iframe src="http://domain.tv/embed/video/<?php echo $yourtext ?>" frameborder="0" framespacing="0" width="100%" height="100%" /></iframe>
```

sorry for my poor english i will adjust it if it doesn't meet your english.

Comment: But what is your question now?

Comment: i need the php code to make it "text.php?content=yourtext" valid (yourtext) being an example

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are trying to get yourtext from  http://domain.com/text.php?content=yourtext

```
<iframe src="http://domain.tv/embed/video/<?= htmlspecialchars($_GET['content']) ?>" frameborder="0" framespacing="0" width="100%" height="100%" /></iframe>
```